# How to retrieve first row of the week for each week

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table that looks like that

```
foo_date   | bar 
---------------
2018-01-01 | bar
2018-01-09 | bar
2018-01-10 | bar
2018-01-20 | bar
```

And I would like to build a request that retrieves,for each week, the row which occurs first in the week.

Cheers

Comment: Are your weeks Monday-Sunday or Sunday-Saturday?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do:

```
select distinct on (datetrunc('week', foo_date)) t.*
from t
order by datetrunc('week', foo_date), foo_date;
```

Answer (score 2):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=5ca86840f04752edda5ddae2b9069fae)

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (year, week)
    foodate, bar
FROM (
    SELECT
        foodate,
        bar,
        EXTRACT('isoyear' FROM foodate) as year,
        EXTRACT('week' FROM foodate) as week
    FROM dates
    ORDER BY foodate
)s
```

`EXTRACT('week'...)` gives the week. So two date in the same week give the same output at this column.

`DISTINCT ON (week)` gives the first (ordered!) row for each week.

[Postgres Date functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html)

Notice the definition of the week:

> The number of the ISO 8601 week-numbering week of the year. By
>   definition, ISO weeks start on Mondays and the first week of a year
>   contains January 4 of that year. In other words, the first Thursday of
>   a year is in week 1 of that year.

---

**Edit**: If you have data from more then a year of course you should add the year as well. Other wise you get the first row of all first weeks of all years for example.

Comment: You better add the `isoyear` also :-)

Comment: @dnoeth of course you are right (if the data set is that big.) Added it :)

Comment: `isoyear` instead of `year`, otherwise you might get strange results over the first/last week of a year

Comment: Thanks for you answer ! Is the subquery really necessary ? Isn't Gordon Linoff answer enough ?

Comment: yes date_trunc is more elegant. I would so it in a subquery anyway to avoid calling the function twice. I am not sure if it would be cached. But with one date_trunc you could safe the year extraction.That's right